# inserting a node at nth position in linked lists not working

Tags: c, linked-list

I am building a student management system in which users add student details dynamically. When I first add 2 students at the beginning of lists, the students are added correctly. However then when I add another student at a position for example 1 (which means I am trying to make this the head node again), the program crashes. I have tried finding out the error but no success. The program just crashes

```
    #pragma warning(disable: 4996)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <Windows.h>





struct students{
    char *name;
    int age;
    char *degree;
    struct students* next;

};

int TotalStudents = 0;

struct students* ptrToHead;

void insertAtBeginning(char name[], int age, char degree[]){

    struct students * temp = (students *)malloc(sizeof(struct students));

    temp->name= strdup(name);
    temp->age = age;
    temp->degree=strdup(degree);
    temp->next = NULL;
    if (ptrToHead != NULL)
    {
        temp->next = ptrToHead;
    }
    ptrToHead = temp;

    //printf("%s\n%d\n%s", temp->name, temp->age, temp->degree);
}
void insertAtAnyPosition(int position, char name[], int age, char degree[]){
    int i = 1;
    struct students * temp = (students *)malloc(sizeof(struct students));
    struct students * temp2 =  ptrToHead, *temp3;
    temp = ptrToHead;
    if (position <= TotalStudents || position <= TotalStudents + 1){
        while (i < position){
            if (i == position - 1)
                temp3 = temp2;


            temp2 = temp2->next;
            i++;
        }
    }
    temp->name = strdup(name);
    temp->age = age;
    temp->degree = strdup(degree);
    temp2->next = temp;
    temp--;
    temp = temp2;

}
void MainMenu();
void addStudent();


void print(){

    struct students* temp = ptrToHead;
    printf("List of Students: ");
    while (temp != NULL){
        printf("\nStudent's Name: %s", temp->name);
        printf("\nStudent's Age: %d", temp->age);
        printf("\nStudent's Degree: %s", temp->degree);
        printf("\nEND - OF - STUDENT");
        temp = temp->next;

    }
    printf("\n");
    Sleep(7000);

    system("cls");
    MainMenu();
}



int main(){

    MainMenu();

    //students * temp= (students *)malloc(sizeof(students));

    //temp->age = 22;
    //temp->degree = "Software Engineering";
    //temp->name = "Fahad Bin Saleem";
    //temp->next = NULL;

    //ptrToHead = temp;

    //

    //printf("Age: %d\n", ptrToHead->age);
    //printf("Name: %s\n", ptrToHead->name);
    //printf("Degree: %s\n", ptrToHead->degree);



    //temp = (students *)malloc(sizeof(students));
    //temp->age = 19;
    //temp->degree = "Electrical Engineering";
    //temp->name = "Rafay Hayat Ali";
    //temp->next = NULL;



    //students * temp1 = ptrToHead;

    //while (temp1->next != NULL){
    //  temp1 = temp1->next;


    //}
    //temp1->next = temp;
    //









    _getch();
    return 0;
}

void MainMenu(){
    int choice;
    printf("Welcome to Student Information Center!\n\n");
    char* mainmenu[] = { "Display All Students", "Add A Student" };

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        printf("%d:  %s\n", i + 1, mainmenu[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\nEnter Your Choice: ");
    scanf_s(" %d", &choice);

    if (choice == 2){
        addStudent();
    }
    if (choice == 1){
        print();
    }


}

void addStudent(){
    int NumberOfStudents;
    int choiceOfAdding;
    char tempName[40];
    char tempDegree[40];
    int tempAge;
    system("cls");



    ptrToHead = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
        printf("  ");
    }
    printf("**ADD A STUDENT**");

    printf("\n\nHow many students do you want to add? Enter Choice: ");
    scanf_s(" %d", &NumberOfStudents);

    printf("\n\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfStudents; i++){
        printf("\n\n");


        printf("Enter Student's Name:  ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets_s(tempName, 40);
        printf("Enter Student's Age:  ");
        scanf_s(" %d", &tempAge);
        printf("Enter Student's Degree:  ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets_s(tempDegree, 40);
        //insert(tempName, tempAge, tempAgeDegree);


        printf("\n\nWhere Do You Want To Add This Student?\n\n1: At The Beginning\n\n2: At A Position N\n\n3: At The End");
        scanf_s(" %d", &choiceOfAdding);
        fflush(stdin);

        if (choiceOfAdding == 1){
            insertAtBeginning(tempName, tempAge, tempDegree);

        }
        else if (choiceOfAdding == 2){
            int position;
            printf("\nEnter the position you want to insert: ");
            scanf_s(" %d", &position);
            insertAtAnyPosition(position, tempName, tempAge, tempDegree);
        }
        TotalStudents++;


        printf("\n\n");

    }
    MainMenu();


}
```

Comment: Do you understand `malloc()`?

Comment: Then why did you do this `struct students * temp = (students *)malloc(sizeof(struct students));` and almost immediately `temp = ptrToHead;`?

Comment: Oh sorry. I edited this code and I might have missed this line out..

Comment: You might get a better response if you take the time to produce a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  (In particular, you should get rid of all the commented-out code, and eliminate the unnecessary blank lines. Also, removing unneeded functions will help readers focus on the actual problem areas in your code.)  In fact, in the process of making an MCVE, you might find the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you have temp2 and temp equal to ptrHead:

```
struct students * temp = (students *)malloc(sizeof(struct students));
struct students * temp2 =  ptrToHead, *temp3;
temp = ptrToHead;
```

you only need one temp pointing to ptrToHead and and additional temp (temp2) to make the swap. In your code you don't need temp3.

I'm no expert but give this a try:

```
void insertAtAnyPosition(int position, char name[], int age, char degree[]){
    int i = 1;
    struct students * temp = (students *)malloc(sizeof(struct students));
    struct students *temp2;
    temp->name = strdup(name);
    temp->age = age;
    temp->degree = strdup(degree);
    temp2 = &ptrToHead;
    if (position <= TotalStudents + 1){
        while (i < position){
            if (i == position - 1)
                temp->next = temp2->next;
                temp2->next = temp;
                temp2 = temp2->next;
                i++;
            }
        }
}
```